# Parsing a line of text and dynamically inserting a line break before a given word?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor element that looks as follows:
`<a href='/somewhere' class='break'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ornare.</a>`

It might say a variety of things, but will generally have the same words within. I want to insert a line break `<br/>` dynamically before the word `amet` (in this example).

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Simple string replace `amet` with `<br>amet` in the innerHTML of that anchor. jQuery is hardly ever the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('#btnBreak').click(function(){
  $('.break').html($('.break').text().split('amet').join('amet <br />'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='/somewhere' class='break'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ornare.</a>

<button id="btnBreak">Break it</button>
```

`.split()` will

> Split a string into an array of substrings

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

`.join()`

> ...joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string. The elements will be separated by a specified separator. The default separator is comma (,).

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

**NOTE** `.replace()` in JavaScript will only replace the **first** occurrence of the string, unless the separator is a Regex

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this through Regex(regular expressions).
Considering you anchor(and giving it an ID to simplify)

`<a href='/somewhere' id='break'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ornare.</a>`

```
$('#break')html($(#break).html().replace(/(amet)/g,'<br/>$1'));
```

What this does is search for the exact world amet on the whole text and replace it with a line break + your desired word,amet in this case.
I'd recommend [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to learn more about regex and [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test your regex with more ease.

Comment: This will actually do *nothing*. `text.replace()` won't even modify `text`, let alone update an `<a>` element anywhere in the page.